# batch script to display multiple folders content

Tags: batch-file

I'm after a batch script that will display the content of specific folders that are listed in a text file, into another text file.

For example:

the text file that will include the folders names will be something like this:

SMPL505
SMPL520
SMPL590

the text file that will include the output - the list of the files in each folder:

SMPL505 SMPL505.JPG SMPL505.TXT ...
SMPL520 SMPL520.JPG SMPL520.TXT ...
SMPL590 SMPL590.JPG SMPL590.TXT ...

Comment: You want a Windows batch file script?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script (which needs some cleaning up), but it will give you the requested output to the file results.txt given all of the full folder names (ex: C:\users\desktop\folder) are in the file test.txt.

```
@echo off

FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do (
cd %%a
dir /b >>temp.txt

FOR /F "tokens=* delims=\" %%a in (temp.txt) do (
echo %%~nxa >>temp2.txt
type temp2.txt | findstr /V "temp.txt temp2.txt" > temp3.txt
move temp3.txt C:\Users\Desktop
del temp.txt temp2.txt
cd C:\Users\Desktop
type temp3.txt >>results.txt
del temp3.txt
)
```